# VBA code Using Data table to populate the userform

Tags: excel, vba

So I am doing some coding for the payroll application. When I run the macro and enter EmployeeNumber in textbox1, I get sent to debugging and third row of code "c=application.worksheet...." is highlighted in yellow. Basically, when I enter employee number in textbox 1, the subsequent information of that employee should get populated by itself. Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong in the code below?

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Me.TextBox2.Enabled = True
Me.TextBox3.Enabled = True
Me.TextBox4.Enabled = True
Me.TextBox5.Enabled = True
Me.TextBox6.Enabled = True
Me.CommandButton2.Visible = True
Me.CommandButton1.Visible = False
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
m = MsgBox("Do You Want To Update Employee Information?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo, "Confirm Update")

If m = vbNo Then Exit Sub


EmployeeNumber = Val(Me.TextBox1.Value)

c = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(MasterData.Range("A:A"),  EmployeeNumber)
If c = 0 Then Exit Sub

r = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(EmployeeNumber,   MasterData.Range("A:A"), 0)
MasterData.Range("B" & r).Value = Me.TextBox2.Value
MasterData.Range("C" & r).Value = Me.TextBox3.Value
MasterData.Range("D" & r).Value = Me.TextBox4.Value
MasterData.Range("E" & r).Value = Me.TextBox5.Value
MasterData.Range("F" & r).Value = Me.TextBox6.Value

Me.TextBox2.Enabled = False
Me.TextBox3.Enabled = False
Me.TextBox4.Enabled = False
Me.TextBox5.Enabled = False
Me.TextBox6.Enabled = False
Me.CommandButton2.Visible = False
Me.CommandButton1.Visible = True
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
Unload.Me
End Sub

Private Sub Label1_Click()

End Sub

Private Sub Label2_Click()

End Sub

Private Sub Label5_Click()

End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
Dim wks As Worksheet
Set wks = Worksheets("MasterData")

EmployeeNumber = Val(Me.TextBox1.Value)

c = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(MasterData.Range("A:A"), EmployeeNumber)

If c = 0 Then
Me.TextBox2.Value = ""
Me.TextBox3.Value = ""
Me.TextBox4.Value = ""
Me.TextBox5.Value = ""
Me.TextBox6.Value = ""
Exit Sub
End If
r = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(EmployeeNumber, MasterData.Range("A:A"), 0)

Me.TextBox2.Value = MasterData.Range("B" & r).Value
Me.TextBox3.Value = MasterData.Range("C" & r).Value
Me.TextBox4.Value = MasterData.Range("D" & r).Value
Me.TextBox5.Value = MasterData.Range("E" & r).Value
Me.TextBox6.Value = MasterData.Range("F" & r).Value


End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Click()

End Sub
```

Comment: How is `MasterData` defined?

Comment: Hello, don't understand what you mean by that. MasterData is a worksheet that has all the Data.

Comment: Dim wks As Worksheet
Set wks = Worksheets("MasterData")

Answer (score 1):

This must not compile - fix that first:
Syntax error in

```
r = Application.worksheerfunction.Match
```

Fixed:

```
r = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match
```

> EDIT: Fix more syntax errors

Replace **MasaterData** with **MasterData**

```
MasaterData.Range("B" & r).Value = Me.TextBox2.Value
MasaterData.Range("C" & r).Value = Me.TextBox3.Value
MasaterData.Range("D" & r).Value = Me.TextBox4.Value
MasaterData.Range("E" & r).Value = Me.TextBox5.Value
MasaterData.Range("F" & r).Value = Me.TextBox6.Value
```

Comment: That has been updated. Now the form appears, but it does nothing.

Comment: I've added the full code for the userform. The userform appears but is not responsive. I've added code in textbox 1, but when I start to typein Userform, I just hear excel sound and then the userform con't even close. I have to force shut the excel. Please help.

Comment: Please help, I saw your profile you also live in BC? I live in Surrey.

Comment: You must first learn to debug by compiling your code first before you do anything ... `Under Debug | Compile VBA Project` I found mispelled datasheet name - see above edit

Comment: I have complied VBA Project and updated the MasterData all through the code. Still same problem. The userform textbox 1 is unresponsive. Won't let me type in

Comment: How is this the same problem as "When I run the macro and enter EmployeeNumber in textbox1, I get sent to debugging and third row of code "c=application.worksheet...." is highlighted in yellow. Basically, when I enter employee number in textbox 1, the subsequent information of that employee should get populated by itself. Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong in the code below?"

Comment: I see what you mean. Yes, technically my question has been answered. But the real solution would be able to type something in the textbox 1. It just doesn't work.

Comment: The issue is you're changing the problem as you change your code. If you change your code and the problem changes - you need to update both the code and the problem description. Ideally with an EDIT quote to let us know what's going on. I'll add another answer below to match your current problem

Answer (score 0):

You can do simple troubleshooting yourself to find the problem by simplifying your code to get one item to work - then expanding the code that works.

The simplest way to troubleshoot VBA problems yourself is to add MSGBOX or DEBUG.PRINT statements to your code to trace what's happening

Currently the issue you have is that you have two locations that handle your text box - the one that's causing you a problem right now is in TextBox_Change - that's going to fire once for every character you type in.

You either want to remove that completely or move it to the TextBox AfterUpdate event - and then decide if you want to remove the duplicate code in the Command Click event

Answer (score 0):

Well Apparently, the userform wasn't enabled "True/False" from properties. That was the reason, I couldn't type anything in textbox 1. I'd like to thanks DbMitch for teaching me the step by step debug approach. The form does its intended function now.